# Are absolute Galois groups condensed?

Tags: galois-theory, condensed-mathematics

Let $k^{s}$ be a separable closure of a field $k$. Is $Gal(k^s/k)$ a condensed group in the sense of condensed mathematics? If condensed, is it always solid?

Comment: What is "condensed group"?

Comment: See [Condensed Mathematics](https://www.math.uni-bonn.de/people/scholze/Condensed.pdf)

Comment: The text is 77 page long. Is there a definiton of condensed group there?

Comment: There is a definition given for $\operatorname{Cond}(\mathsf{C})$ for any category $\mathsf{C}$.
The particular case $\mathsf{C} = \mathsf{Grp}$ of the category of groups is what you're looking for. (check out p.7 of the link above)

Comment: @lush: page 7 says that Cond(C) is a functor from the category of profinite sets to groups.  Again: what is a "condensed group"?

Comment: @dodd page 7 defines what the category $\operatorname{Cond}(\mathsf{C})$ is.
It in particular literally states:
"[...] a condensed set/ring/group/... is a functor ..." spelling out in detail what a condensed group is.

Comment: A condensed group is a sheaf of groups on the site of profinite sets (where covers are finite families of jointly surjective maps). They are closely related to topological groups.

Comment: @PeterScholze: So a condensed group is not a group? Everything is related to everything else. Sometimes even closely related.

Comment: A condensed group "is" a group just as much as a topological group "is" a group: It's not a property of an abstract group, but extra structure.

Comment: @dodd This is admittedly an abuse of language. In this perspective you can identify topological groups (under some conditions) with sheaves in Cond(C) they define. This is similar to how in algebraic geometry schemes are identified with their functors of points, and at higher level you talk about such a functor (or sheaf) being a scheme. The question can then be read as: does this Galois group indeed define a condensed group, and is it solid?

Answer (score 10):

Like any profinite group (or much more general types of topological groups, such as compactly generated ones), you can consider it as a condensed group in the sense of condensed mathematics. In fact, that's the perspective I am taking, and it is useful for thinking about say continuous group cohomology of $\mathrm{Gal}(k^s/k)$.

On the other hand, "solid" is an adjective that pertains only to condensed *abelian* groups. But all profinite abelian groups are solid -- in fact, the category of solid abelian groups is a full subcategory of condensed abelian groups stable under all limits and colimits, and containing all discrete objects -- so if $\mathrm{Gal}(k^s/k)$ happens to be abelian, it is solid.